# Function signature as type in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Is there a way to declare something like

```
type do = ('a -> 'b)
```

in OCaml? Specifically, to declare a function signature as a type

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How would you use this type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For free types `'a` and '`b`,`'a -> 'b` is not the type of any well behaved OCaml function, because it requires the function to produce a value of an arbitrary type.

So, you can't give a name to a type with unbound parameters:

```
# type uabfun = 'a -> 'b
Error: Unbound type parameter 'a
```

If you use specific types, there's no problem giving it a name:

```
# type iifun = int -> int;;
type iifun = int -> int
```

If type types `'a` and `'b` are parameters (rather than being free), there is also no problem:

```
# type ('a, 'b) abfun = 'a -> 'b;;
type ('a, 'b) abfun = 'a -> 'b
```

Comment: The answer of Jeffrey Scofield is excellent. I just want to add a reference for variant type in OCaml: https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/variants.html